# Same taxonomy in two content type

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have two content types *Blog* and *Stay* which use the same taxonomy *Location*. I have two or more posts use same term *Cyclades*.

Is it possible when a user clicks on a *Cyclades* term link in a *Blog* post to only show posts from *Blog* content on the taxonomy page? Likewise, when a user clicks on *Cyclades* in a *Stay* post, to show only *Stay* content on the page?

I know i can create two different taxonomy for each content type, but I dont want this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can have same taxonomy being used by multiple content types.

You can achieve this by using 2 options
1. Overriding node.tpl.php for the taxonomy page. Here you can create two separate tpl files specific two different content types.
2. Create PAGE display of VIEWs and pass "type" as an argument. Based on this argument you can always display the teasers belonging only to the desited "Content Type."

Option # 2 is little easier from implementation point of view whereing Option # 1 though could little time consuming but will be better from performance perspective.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I create it with views and rewrite url.